# Android: 9-patch image vs Shape vs Multi icon

Tags: android, user-interface

Some people from our company create some rule about UI design for Web, Android and iOS. They give us a bunch of icon for each platform. But when i look at Android platform icon, they using multi icon to create 1 icon. For example, button background, they use these 3 icon, 1 for left side, 1 for right size and 1 stretchable for middle.

[image] [image] [image]

I think this is how web normally design button background. But i don't think i should do the same for Android (Maybe iOS also don't do it this way but since i only work with iOS for a short time, i not really sure). Normally i would use a Shape or 9-patch drawable for this kind of background. So here i have 2 question:

1. Which 1 should i use for button background in this example. A shape? A 9-patch drawable? Or multiple icon like this? And which one is worst to use?
2. If i must have to use multiple icon like this, how to put multiple icon like them into single background?

If their way of doing thing here is incorrect, i need some good reason to talk to them and make them change their mind. So any1 please help me clear about this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9-patch should be the first choice and then is shape. Don't use 3 icon.

9-patch is more easy to use and easy to change if the further design changes. When using shape, you need to define the corresponding XML. If in next version, the background color changes, you need to modify the XML, but with 9-patch you just need to replace the resource file.

The other benefit is that, 9-patch can be created in UI side, programmer's don't have to re-manipulate it if the resource is correctly created. But with shape, programmer needs to know the RGB color, and need to code the XML.

3 icon is not suitable here. First, you have other better options. Second, 3 icon means you need to create 3 views for each of them. Third, the button should have different effect when user click it, with other two options you can simply define selectors, but with 3 icon, there's no elegant solution.

Comment: Thank for your explain. I know it wrong to use 3 icon like this on Android. But just a side question, do you know about iOS. Does 3 icon like that suit for iOS. Since i don't think iOS have something like 9-patch or shape.

Comment: @mameo I'm not familiar with iOS development, but iOS have some similar mechanism like 9-patch. In my team, we don't use 3-icon in Android and iOS.

Comment: Ah thank anyway. I will dig in for more information about iOS myself later

Comment: I'd use a shape as the 1st choice, as it takes less bytes. If not appliable (many colours or an icon inside), then surely use a 9 patch.